# Spring XML configure classpath

Tags: java, spring

I have a project (A) that depends on another local project (B).

In A), the spring.xml goes something like

`import resource="classpath:company/beandef.xml"/>`

However, this beandef.xml is located in another directory (project B directory) **outside** of Project A source root. Is there a way to configure the "classpath" to include an outside directory? The IDE I'm using is IntelliJ.

Comment: You should write a maven task to copy resources of parent project into resources of child project

Comment: You should be using Maven or Gradle to manage dependencies generally. Don't copy resource between projects, just add them as dependencies. (IntelliJ and Eclipse will both set their classpaths from Maven or Gradle build specifications.)

Comment: I used gradle to link my projects together (number 2. in https://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/compile-gradle-project-with-another-project-as-a-dependency/), but because the projects are in different directories, its not seeing the resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
<import resource="classpath:company/beandef.xml"/>
```

This import statement looks at classpath for the package/folder called "company" in dependent projects or in your project. You cannot make any directory in project B as root directory from project A. You can quickly check for whether package "company" is under root directory or not by going to external Libraries folder in IntelliJ. 
  Go to external Libraries folder in IntelliJ and look for an entry of Project B. Once Project B entry expanded, there you should be an entry for package "company". If not company is not under root directory/classpath.